# Is 'At hand' a formal idiom?

Tags: word-choice

I've read that idioms are generally an aspect of informal language and also that  some of these idioms can be used in formal writing. **'At hand'** is an idiom which I think it can be used in  **formal** writing (eg. to mean **available** as in '**the new edition is now at hand'**) but at the same time it is still an idiomatic expression. **So, is it formal or informal?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's used in a formal register (it is, for your records), I don't think *at hand* means what you think it means. It's used to mean "close by", either literally or figuratively, but it doesn't really mean "available" in the sense you're trying to ascribe to the idiom. Take a look at its dictionary entry at https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/at_hand: the second sense is "**Readily** accessible **when needed**.", and that's as close as you can get to the desired meaning.

Comment: The expression is equally acceptable in both formal and informal contexts.

Comment: @userr2684291 Here in Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary, it provides an example saying:  'we want to ensure that help is 'at hand'(=easily available) for all children suffering from abuse'. Isn't it the same as : 'we want to ensure that help is 'available' for all children suffering from abuse'?  please clarify.

Comment: Yeah, note the difference between *easily available* (= *readily accessible*) and *obtainable*, which is what *available* means in context of a book's new edition that's just been published.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression

> **at hand**

can be used both formally and informally, and

> **on hand** - *immediately available*
>
> **to hand** - *in one's hand (BrE)*

are the same.